# Multiple Data source in hibernate annotation throwing No Session found for current thread error

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-annotations

I am using spring 4 & hibernate annotation in my web app. Everything works fine with single datasource. When I add second datasource I am getting No session for current thread error.

Here is the code.

```
public abstract class PortalAbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

private final Class<T> persistentClass;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public PortalAbstractDao() {
    this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
            .getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("eportalSessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T getByKey(PK key) {
    return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
}

public void persist(T entity) {
    getSession().persist(entity);
}

public void delete(T entity) {
    getSession().delete(entity);
}

protected Criteria createEntityCriteria() {
    return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
}
```

}

DAO Implementation

```
@Repository("portalDao")
public class PortalDaoImpl extends PortalAbstractDao<Integer, PortalAsset> implements PortalDao {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<PortalAsset> findAllAssets() {
        //      Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(
        //              "select id,CSC_ASSET_TAG,SERIAL_NO,IBM_ASSET_TAG from sgh_assets where CSC_ASSET_TAG like :term");
        //      query.setString("term", "%gwls1208%");
        Criteria criteria = getSession()
                .createCriteria(PortalAsset.class)
                .setMaxResults(20)
                .setProjection(
                        Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
                                .add(Projections.property("ctcassettag"), "ctcassettag")
                                .add(Projections.property("serialno"), "serialno")
                                .add(Projections.property("ibmassettag"), "ibmassettag")
                                .add(Projections.property("block"), "block")
                                .add(Projections.property("level"), "level").add(Projections.property("room"), "room"))
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(PortalAsset.class));
        return (List<PortalAsset>) criteria.list();
    }
}
```

Hibernate configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.span.vms.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.span.vms.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("eportalSessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean eportalSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(eportalDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.ctc.pm.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource eportalDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.eportal.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.eportal.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.eportal.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Service Implementation

```
@Service("portalService")
public class PortalServiceImpl implements PortalService {
    @Autowired
    private PortalDao dao;

    @Override
    public List<PortalAsset> findAllAssets() {
        return dao.findAllAssets();
    }

}
```

Service Interface

```
public interface PortalDao {
    List<PortalAsset> findAllAssets();
}
```

When I run `List<PortalAsset> assets = portalService.findAllAssets();` I am getting no session for current thread error where the primary datasource is working fine. What is the mistake I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your hibernate configuration file it should be..

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.span.vms.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.span.vms.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "eportalSessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean eportalSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(eportalDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.ctc.pm.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource eportalDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.eportal.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.eportal.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.eportal.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "txManager1")
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "txManager2")
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(eportalSessionFactory());
        return txManager;
    }
```

and In service layer, at @Transactional annotation specify the name of transaction manager which you want to use.

Comment: Same error. no session for current thread. ( Also for your info I have another datasource with primary annotation it is working fine)

Comment: I see that transactionManager is ambiguos. It is creating txManager with primary SessionFactory.

Comment: Thanks bro. It's working fine after adding different transaction manager. update your answer. I wil make right mark.

Comment: what did you do? added another txManager in same config class or created different hibernate config class

Comment: I added another transactionmanager method inside hibernate config. at my service I metioned @Transactional("txmgrname").